# same project with different name gives Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

Im repeating a similar question but with different scenario. I imported similar project but with different name in eclipse(I change the name of project in .project file). I checked all the options like clean the project, run configuration, removing and adding externals jars but still im getting the Error: Could not find or load main class.

Comment: Elaborate how you got this error. Did you click the 'run' button? Are you running something on the command line?

Comment: I right click the class with main method and then run

Comment: Build the project and then run. Possiblity that the sources are not compiled yet.

Comment: I did evrything build it again clean it evryoption

Comment: Show us the source, and the project layout, and what's in the .classpath file. What does the run configuration look like? All of this may look fine to you, but no one else has seen them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd delete the project in your eclipse view (right click the project, pick 'delete'). When the popup comes up, do NOT check the 'delete files on disk' option.

Then, right click in the package explorer and pick import>existing project into eclipse...

and then re-import it.

Editing the .project file directly is not something eclipse was designed for.